# Annotation processor: file writing from the process() method

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I wrote an annotation processor and i'd like to write some information into a text file. In my class I'm extending the `AbstractProcessor` and overriding the

`public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv)`

and

`public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv)`

methods.

In the `init()` method I'm creating a new `PrintWriter` (eg. this way: `writer = new PrintWriter("output.csv", "UTF-8");`)

with which I print some text into a file in the `process()` method.

The **problem** is, that (as I use my processor on multiple sources in different packages) the file (`output.csv`) always gets recreated when a new source is being processed (because a new Processor object is created each time). This way only the lastly processed source's information gets into the text file, although I want to acquire information from **all** of the annotated methods (from different sources) into **one** text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.csv", true));

Comment: Thank you very much, by appending to the stream it works!